# window.alert in html link not showing on iOS 9.0.2 iPad with Cordova 3.9.1 and Xcode 7.0.1

Tags: ios, cordova, alert

Can't get the basic simple HelloWorld index.html page to show a simple javascript window.alert neither in the iOS simulator nor on the device.

```
<a href="javascript:window.alert('Alert 1’);”>Alert 1</a>
<a href="#" onclick="sampleFunction('Alert 2’);”>Alert 2</a>
```

Even a simple function call is not triggered:

```
<a href="#" onclick="sampleFunction('Simple function call’);”>Simple function call</a>
```

The following message is shown three times when clicking once a link.

```
<CATransformLayer: 0x14e687620> - changing property masksToBounds in transform-only layer, will have no effect
```

The device plugin is working, so the API is correctly initialised. Features CDVDevice, CDVNotification, CDVVibration are added to the config.xml. I think all files are correctly in place and no warnings are shown during build.

More distracting is, that if a window.alert is added to the receivedEvent function of the app object the alert is showing up.

I read quite a few related entries, but now i am out of options.

iPad mini 2 iOS 9.0.2, Xcode 7.0.1, Cordova 5.3.3 and device.cordova 3.9.1

Is this perhaps a problem of the version combination?

Comment: read the dialogs plugin installation and usage https://github.com/apache/cordova-plugin-dialogs

Comment: Thank you @jcesarmobile - i did. When putting the cordova.js and js/index.js references into the head portion of index.html instead of the body navigator.notification.alert is working. I will not investigate further and will not use window.alert. I read something about a different event handling of the iOS 9 UIWebView.